# What does "well" mean, in the phrase "well before"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, adverbs

The [book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=oIYNBodW-ZEC&pg=PR11&lpg=PR11&dq=%22the%20idea%20for%20the%20book%20came%20well%22&source=bl&ots=peJ0gustJK&sig=ACfU3U1I-aaooZ8uZw6jVBrylyJjTeGmNQ&hl=en&sa=X&) "Moneyball: The Art of Winning an Unfair Game by By Michael Lewis" says

> But the idea for the book came **well** before I had good reason to
>   write it – before I had a story to fall in love with.

What does *well* mean here? Does that mean "already", "exactly" or some other meaning?

Comment: As a reminder, you are expected to demonstrate your initial research efforts, such as consulting references. The [second dictionary definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/well_1) of *well* in Macmillan, for instance, explicitly offers the sense of *used for emphasizing that a period of time or a distance is long*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Well before" is "before", and not just "before", but "quite a bit before", or "significantly before." In other words, there was enough time between the *idea* for the book and the *storyline*, that there can be no doubt which came first.